# applescript does not find command line tool under /usr/local/bin

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, directory, applescript

AppleScript does not find a command line tool located in `/usr/local/bin/`.

I've got the following AppleScript command:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/bitbar refresh"
```

It results in the error:

```
error "env: node: No such file or directory" number 127
```

I checked the directory and the command line tool is indeed in that location. AppleScript does find other tolls installed there, such as `brew`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initially adding a new path (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/`) to the shells [`PATH`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Variables) variable before running the `bitbar refresh` command.

For instance, change your [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) as follows:

```c
do shell script "PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; bitbar refresh"
```